# How to grep within a loop to exclude?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a `NPM_RESERVED_SCOPE` that contains a comma-separated list of forbidden scope.

I have a `NPM_ALLOWED_DEV_DEPENDENCIES_PACKAGES` that contains a comma-separated list of exception.

```
NPM_RESERVED_SCOPE=@privatescope,@secondary
NPM_ALLOWED_DEV_DEPENDENCIES_PACKAGES="@privatescope/private-project-scripts,@privatescope/private-project-ci-build,@privatescope/private-project-ci-test,@privatescope/private-project-ci-release,@privatescope/private-project-ci-deploy,@privatescope/private-project-ci-release-transitive"


for i in $(echo ${NPM_RESERVED_SCOPES} | sed "s/,/ /g")
  do
    for j in $(echo ${NPM_ALLOWED_DEV_DEPENDENCIES_PACKAGES} | sed "s/,/ /g")
    do
      if [[ $(cat package.json | jq .devDependencies | grep "$i/" | grep -v "$j") ]]; then
        echo "[Error] GitHub release abort. Reason: devDependencies within scope $i are forbidden."
        exit 1
      fi
    done
  done
```

I want this script to passe if the `devDependencies` does not contains any of the `NPM_RESERVED_SCOPES`, except the list of exception.

This is the file `package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
     "@privatescope/private-project-ci-build": "^1.0.5",
     "@privatescope/private-project-ci-deploy": "^1.0.7",
     "@privatescope/private-project-ci-release": "^1.0.5",
     "@privatescope/private-project-release-transitive": "^1.0.6",
     "@privatescope/private-project-test": "^1.0.4",
     "@privatescope/private-project": "^0.15.22"
   }
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Please ad examples of the files

Comment: ok @dawg I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the lists into extended patterns by replacing `,` with `|` and wrapping the list in `@(...)`.

```
reserved="@(${NPM_RESERVED_SCOPE//,/|})"
allowed="@(${NPM_ALLOWED_DEV_DEPENDENCIES_PACKAGES//,/|})"
```

Now pattern matching can replace the nested for loops.`a = @(x|y|z)` if `a` matches any one of the patterns `x`, `y`, or `z`.

```
while IFS= read -r dep; do
  if [[ $dep = $reserved && $dep != $allowed ]]; then
      echo "[Error] GitHub release abort. Reason: $dep within scope $i is forbidden." >&2
      exit 1
  fi
done < <( jq .devDependencies '.devDependencies' )
```